# reactjs - Testing a component toHaveAttribute works in one case but fails in another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, styled-components, react-testing-library

I'm writing a test with `jest`, `jest-dom` and `react-testing-library`.

I have 2 components in my React app:

```js
// Component 1

<NavItem
  icon={<Icon />}
  text="Homepage"
  toggled={toggled}
  to={routesPaths.homepage}
  disabled={isDatabaseEmpty}
  dataTestId="sidebar-homepage"
/>

// <NavItem> is an instance of <Container> which extends <Link> with styled-components:

const Container = styled(Link)`
  ${container}
`;

<Container
  active={isActive}
  toggled={toggled ? 1 : 0}
  to={to}
  disabled={disabled}
  data-testid={dataTestId}
>
  {icon}
  <Text toggled={toggled}>{text}</Text>
</Container>
```

```js
// Component 2

<Segment
  onClick={() => setSelectedSegment(segmentTitle)}
  isActive={isCurrentMonth}
  key={key}
  label="This month"
  dataTestId="segment-this-month"
/>

// <Segment> is an instance of <SegmentContainer> which extends a <div> with styled-component:

const SegmentContainer = styled.div<{ isActive: boolean }>`
  ${segment}
`;

<SegmentContainer isActive={isActive} onClick={onClick} data-testid={dataTestId}>
  {label}
</SegmentContainer>
```

When I query these components by test id (in the same test) only one of them passes:

```js
const sidebarElement = screen.getByTestId('sidebar-homepage') // ✅ Passes
expect(sidebarElement).toHaveAttribute('active', '1'); // ✅ Passes

const segmentThisMonth = screen.getByTestId('segment-this-month') // ✅ Passes
expect(segmentThisMonth).toHaveAttribute('isActive', '1'); // ❌ Fails

// Error summary
//
// expect(element).toHaveAttribute("isActive", "1") // element.getAttribute("isActive") === "1"
// Expected the element to have attribute:
//   isActive="1"
// Received:
//   null
```

Why isn't `isActive` being received when querying the element in the later case?

Is there something special about `styled<Link>` that's not there when `styled.div`?

Needless to say, but the `isActive` prop works fine when running the app normally.

Comment: Give sure that your `segmentThisMonth` is not `null`? Maybe the  `SegmentContainer` component not render in your test case.

Comment: If I `console.log(segmentThisMonth)` I get all of the `HTMLDivElement` details, so it's definitely there.

Comment: `active` and `isActive` are component props, not HTML attributes. `.toHaveAttribute` cannot look at what props your component has, only the HTML attributes in the DOM. Inspect your application while its running and make sure the attributes you expect are there. If not, you need to find a different way to test your functionality.

Comment: When I console.log the elements I get `HTMLAnchorElement` and `HTMLDivElement` respectively.

Both have a `_reactEventHandlers$d3u5mqfrdea'` at the end of the object with the available attributes.

The 1st component has: `active: 1, toggled: 1, disabled: false, className: "sc-gjNGvZ hdlVnc", onClick=[Function: onClick], etc...`.

The 2nd component only has: `onClick: [Function: onClick], children: 'This month', className: 'sc-llYToB faxECz'`.